# Using `gui`, `guifg`, `guibg`, `guisp` is deprecated - Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I've started working on my Neovim config written in Lua.
Every time I reopen Neovim I have this error and I don't know what it represents or how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: These errors come from your [bufferline.nvim](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim) plugin. The author has changed recently definitions of highlight groups.

You must change definitions for hl groups in your configuration as described by deprecation messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just fixed the error message
if you are using Neovim-from-scratch
then go to `bufferline.lua`:

1. replace `guifg` to `fg`
2. same thing for `guibg` to just `bg` and then
3. replace `'gui = italic'` to `'underline = true'`
4. that's it

If you are not using Neovim-from-scratch then
follow the instruction on error message
live grep on config file search for guibg
go to the file found replace instructed

I would like to capture screen shot though, I have not set yet on my newly installed linux